# Pythagorean Trig Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I'm about to teach basic Pythgorean trig identities and went through the textbook exercise but I'm stuck on one.

Show

$$\sec^2 A = \frac{ \mathrm{cosec} A}{ \mathrm{cosec} A - \sin A}$$

Can someone help please?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Multiply L.H.S by $\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin{x}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\csc A}{\csc A- \sin A}$$
$$=\frac1{1-\sin^2A}(\text{multiplying the numerator & the denominator by }\sin A )$$
$$=\frac1{\cos^2A}=\sec^2A$$

Answer (score 3):

In order to simplify this, I would first convert the $\csc A$ to $\frac{1}{\sin A}$. With this, I would get the following:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\frac{1}{\sin A}}{\frac{1}{\sin A}-\sin A}\end{align}$$

Now I can easily simplify from here by making the denominator between $\frac{1}{\sin A}$ and $\sin A$ the same. This would give me, for the denominator:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1 - \sin^2 A}{\sin A}
\end{align}$$

I can convert $1-\sin^2 A$ to $\cos^2 A$ and I would get the following: 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sin A}}{\frac{\cos^2A}{\sin A}}$$

Now you can see that I can easily cancel out the $\sin A$ from the numerator and denominator and I would be left with $\frac{1}{\cos^2A}$ which is the same as $\mathrm{sec^2} A$

Comment: +1 for getting rid of $\csc$ and $\sec$ as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\csc A}{\csc A - \sin A} = \frac{\csc A}{\csc A - \sin A}\cdot\frac{\csc A}{\csc A} = \frac{\csc^2 A}{\csc^2 A -\sin A\csc A}$$
$$ = \frac{\csc^2 A}{\csc^2 A -1}=\frac{\csc^2 A}{\cot^2A}=\tan^2 A\csc^2A=\tan^2 A(\cot^2A+1)$$
$$=\tan^2 A \cot^2 A + \tan^2 A = 1 + \tan^2 A = \sec^2 A$$